# how to connect to remote mysql database from my cordova app?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, cordova, mobile

I have a cordova application that i want to connect to a remote mysql database. Actually i want to insert to the database some data (for example a username). Can you help me with a simple example please? i have read so many things on internet, but nothing works on cordova. I know that i must use AJAX to call a php script, and it works fine on a simple web application, but not in cordova. Can you give me an example code please? i need just to take the value (for example a string) of a form's input and by submitting to store the data to the remote mysql database. Any help really appreciate.

Comment: Show us your code, it should work as it is exactly the same. Check the console for any errors and check your `meta` tags as the default Cordova `index.html` prevents a lot of request based actions for security reason.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src 'self' data: content:;">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/libs/jqueryui/css/base/minified/jquery-ui.css" >
    <script>

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="demo"></div>
    <div data-role='page' id='UsersSignUp'>
        <div data-role='header' class='ui-content'>
            <h1>Sign up for free</h1>
            <p>please fill out the form</p>
        </div>
        <div data-role='main' class='ui-content'>
            <form id="signupForm">
                <input type='text' id='username' name='username'>
                <input type='button' value='submit' class='blink' id="SignUpAjaxButton">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div data-role='footer'>
            <p>&copy; OnLineGym.com</p>
            <p>Created by <a href='mailto:teo.godgift4@gmail.com'>Teo Theodoridis</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/jquery-ajaxtransport-xdomainrequest/jquery.xdomainrequest.min"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/jqueryui/css/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var app = {
// Application Constructor
initialize: function () {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready',  this.onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);
},
// deviceready Event Handler
//
// Bind any cordova events here. Common events are:
// 'pause', 'resume', etc.
onDeviceReady: function () {
    this.receivedEvent('deviceready');

},
// Update DOM on a Received Event
receivedEvent: function (id) {
    var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
    var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
    var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

    listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
    receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

    console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
}
};

app.initialize();

document.getElementById("SignUpAjaxButton").addEventListener("click",  loadDoc);

function loadDoc() {
var str0 = $('#username').val();
window.alert(str0);
/* var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
 if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
 }
 };
 xhttp.open("GET", "http://127.0.0.1/register.php?q="+str0, true);
 xhttp.send(); */
}
;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AngularJS then you could do an AJAX call like this:

```
var loadData = function () {
    var config = {
        params: { 
            whatever: xy
        },
        timeout: 15000
    };
    var url = 'http://yourdomain/api/data';
    return $http.get(url, config);
};
```

Don't forget to inject the http module in your angular service:

```
AngularApp.factory('DataService', function ($http) {
```

And at least check your Content-Security-Policy in your index.html file, you have to allow all your calls in your cordova app like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
    content="
    default-src * 'self';
    img-src 'self' data:;
    style-src 'self'; 
    script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';
    ">
```

Then you could do on your server what ever you want e.g. read, write mysql database.

Comment: Actually, i dont use Angular. I use JQuery Mobile